# How to make a dynamic route my homepage in Nuxt / Netlify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify-cms

I have a single page site with some content management on the homepage.

The homepage content file is here
`/content/index.md`

which references the template home in
`/pages/_home.vue`

So I want the build step to spit out an index.html. It works in dev but when I `npm run generate` there is no index in the /dist directory. This also means when I push up to Netlify, the homepage is a 404.

Do I need to set this routing up explicitly in the nuxt config?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by renaming `/pages/_home.vue` to `/pages/index.vue`. You don't have to use the dynamic page convention if its a standalone page and you still get to use content